Alternative solution for the Dangling Else Problem
I understand that one of the ways to solve the Dangling Else Problem is by imposing innermost binding.
So, we have to transform the following ambiguous grammar:
S → if b then S | if b then S else S | c 

to the unambiguous grammar:
S → M | U
M → if b then M else M | c
U → if b then S | if b then M else U

This is the solution that I see proposed everywhere I look. I, however, am not convinced that S -> M | U is necessary. Can't I simply get rid of it and obtain the following grammar?
U → if b then U | if b then M else U | c
M → if b then M else M | c

Where U is the starting symbol.
